# docker mysql start failed, unable to create temporary file, permission denied

Tags: mysql, docker

ubuntu 14.04
docker 1.8.2 
mysql is latest official image 
here is my command

```
vm:~$ docker run --name mysql -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 mysql
```

and the tips:

```
Running mysql_install_db
2015-09-22 08:42:13 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.26) starting as process 15 ...
2015-09-22 08:42:13 15 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-09-22 08:42:13 15 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-09-22 08:42:13 15 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-09-22 08:42:13 15 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-09-22 08:42:13 15 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2015-09-22 08:42:13 15 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-09-22 08:42:13 15 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibhzPhSc' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2015-09-22 08:42:13 7f962ed20720  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2015-09-22 08:42:13 15 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-09-22 08:42:13 15 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-09-22 08:42:13 15 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-09-22 08:42:13 15 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-09-22 08:42:13 15 [Note] Binlog end
2015-09-22 08:42:13 15 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Anyone has suggestion?

Comment: See if this helps -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/442536/mysql-couldnt-write-to-tmp-then-failed-to-restart

Comment: So strange！The command works when I restart the visual machine...